# Using AttributeConverter for collection logs ERROR HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using the following converter to persist a set of strings as comma-separated-values (with escaping) in a single `VARCHAR` database column:

```java
public class StringSetConverter implements AttributeConverter<Set<String>, String> {

   @Override
   public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Set<String> stringSet) {
      if (stringSet == null) {
         return null;
      }
      // remove null-strings and empty strings, escape commas
      return stringSet.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).filter(s -> s.length() > 0)
                    .map(s -> s.replace(",", "\\,"))
                    .sorted().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
   }

   @Override
   public Set<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbString) {
      if (dbString == null) {
        return new HashSet<>();
      }
      Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
      String[] items = dbString.split("(?<=[^\\\\]),");
      for (String item : items) {
         if (item.length() > 0) {
            result.add(item.replace("\\,", ","));
         }
      }
      return result;
   }
}
```

Usage on the JPA entities:

```java
    @Column(name = "GRANTED_PRIVILEGES", nullable = false, length = 4000)
    @Convert(converter = StringSetConverter.class)
    private Set<String> grantedPrivileges;

    @Column(name = "DENIED_PRIVILEGES", nullable = false, length = 4000)
    @Convert(converter = StringSetConverter.class)
    private Set<String> deniedPrivileges;
```

**The converter works really well** - the set of strings gets properly persisted and can be read back without any issues.

The only caveat is the **errors that Hibernate log**s when starting the Spring Boot app that uses these entities:

```
    ERROR o.h.m.i.MetadataContext : HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : 
        anonymized.AuthorityDO_#grantedPrivileges; 
        expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; 
        encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.SetAttribute 
    ERROR  o.h.m.i.MetadataContext : HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : 
        anonymized.AuthorityDO_#deniedPrivileges; 
        expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; 
        encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.SetAttribute
```

What issue does Hibernate have with my JPA `AttributeConverter`?
Apart from logging errors, Hibernate eventually works well with the converter - so where's the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping is wrong because you try to use collection for the singular attribute. According to the JPA specification (see *6.2.1.1 Canonical Metamodel* section):

> For every persistent collection-valued attribute `z` declared by class `X`, where the element type of `z` is `Z`, the metamodel class must contain a declaration as follows:
>
> - if the collection type of `z` is `java.util.Set`, then
>
>   `public static volatile SetAttribute<X, Z> z;`

But, hibernate expects that you will use `@ElementCollection`, `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` association for the collection attribute.

I would suggest you to use some wrapper class for your custom type:

```java
public class StringSet {
  private Set<String> stringSet;
  // ...
}

public class StringSetConverter implements AttributeConverter<StringSet, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(StringSet stringSet) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public StringSet convertToEntityAttribute(String dbString) {
       // ...
    }
}

@Column(name = "GRANTED_PRIVILEGES", nullable = false, length = 4000)
@Convert(converter = StringSetConverter.class)
private StringSet grantedPrivileges;
```