# JPA Attribute Converter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have some problem when I input value like this `[]` or `[""]` to insert data base.
It will infinity loop not stop.
I don't know why.
Example source code below.

```
@Entity("student")
class Student {
......
    @Column(name = "something")
    @Convert(converter = CustomConverter.class)
    private List<String> something;

}
```

```
@Converter
public class CustomConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final List<String> param) {
        if (param == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (param.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return String.join(",", param);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(final String param) {
        if (param == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (param.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return Arrays.asList(param.split(","));
    }
}
```

But when I use value valid is working fine like this value `["vanda","nico"]`

**Question** how to solve it and why this process loop forever ?
Thank you.

Comment: How do you know it loops forever? There's nothing that suggests a loop, are you sure you don't get an exception (that might get hidden)?

Comment: Yes it loop for long time so I just assume it loop not stop.

Comment: I do not get any exception it still in loop.

Comment: There are no loops. Don't assume things. Run it through a debugger and see what happens.

Comment: yes It not have loop but I still call this function many time.

Comment: @Mrempty You should not use `AttributeConverter` for collections. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61385330/) post. By the way, the author tried to do the same thing as you.

Comment: @SternK thank you but not the same my issues

Comment: @SternK @kayaman I still can't not fine error. do you have any example code with it `AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> `